# Change Content-Type for certain requests in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular 6 application that makes API calls to a Node/Express server. I'm using an HTTP interceptor to add a couple of headers the app needs, and also it sets the 'Content-Type' to 'application/json' as all the requests expect JSON data. The new header looks like this:

```
newHeader = {
    withCredentials : true,
    headers: new HttpHeaders ({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'X_TOKEN_AUTH': authToken,
      'X_IDUSER': user_id
    })
  };
```

But now I need to upload images to the backend, so one of the routes of the server must expect non JSON data coming in the body.

What I want to do is:

*In the Angular app, add the right header to the POST request, like this:

```
const url = `${SERVER_URL}/fileupload`;
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};

return this.httpClient.post(url, formData, httpOptions)
```

*In the HTTP interceptor, check if the request has a 'Content-Type' header. In that case, use it instead of the default 'application/json'. In the interceptor I've logged the headers in the request it receives:

```
intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  [....]

  console.log('HTTP REQ:', req.headers);
}
```

And this is what it prints:

[image]

As you can see, there's nothing related to the headers. What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try req.headers.has('Content-Type')

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following Eliseo suggestion, this is what I've done:

```
let contentType = 'application/json';

// Check if the incoming request has an specific content type in the header
if (req.headers.has('Content-Type'))
  contentType = req.headers.get('Content-Type');
```

Now I can use `contentType` to set the right header for the upload route.

Comment: You could just check `if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')` and only if there's no `Content-Type` in the headers, append it.